# DynamoDB List data-type issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-php-sdk

According this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/dynamodb-json-and-array-marshaling-for-php/), DynamoDB supports map (M) and list (L) types, but when I'm trying to create a table with (L) type, I'm getting an error:

> ValidationException (client): 1 validation error detected: Value 'L' at 'attributeDefinitions.2.member.attributeType' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [B, N, S]

It is happening after adding `ThreadReplyIds` attribute to a Table info:

```
[
    'AttributeDefinitions' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'UserId',
            'AttributeType' => 'N',
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'ThreadReplyIds', // <<---
            'AttributeType' => 'L',
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'Title',
            'AttributeType' => 'S',
        ],
    ],
    'KeySchema' => [
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'UserId',
            'KeyType' => 'HASH',
        ],
        [
            'AttributeName' => 'Title',
            'KeyType' => 'RANGE',
        ],
    ],
    'ProvisionedThroughput' => [
        'ReadCapacityUnits' => 5,
        'WriteCapacityUnits' => 5,
    ],
    'TableName' => 'Thread',
]
```

My goal is to store a list or set of integer values for `ThreadReplyIds`.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first, I thought it might be the version of the SDK that you are using. But after some reading through the documentation, it seems that when creating a table, the AttributeType for any AttributeDefinition can only be one of 'S|N|B' (meaning 'String', 'Number', or 'Binary'). Reference: [PHP SDK DynamoDB AttributeDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#shape-attributedefinition).

This makes sense, since you can't use a List in your KeySchema anyway. It is therefore unnecessary to define an Attribute for your List when creating the table. You can always add this Attribute to whatever data you want when Putting or Updating Items in your table after it has been created. See here: [PHP SDK DynamoDB PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-dynamodb-2012-08-10.html#putitem)

Comment: This is exactly what I though of. Anyway, it looks confusing to be we cannot define such attribute upfront

Comment: Well, it is a non-relational storage system, so any one item could differ from the next entirely (except for the keys). The SDK only needs information about which attributes to use for keys when creating the table.

Comment: And you are able to create Global Secondary Index or Local Secondary Index on any top-level JSON element

Comment: I am still not sure how can I add a Global Secondary Index on a key of type list? This means the indexes can only be created on key belonging to one of the types [S,N,B]. What if we want to sort a list of items within an item? For instance, shops owned by a user? What kind of GSI will then I have to maintain?